# Javascript: show/hide HTML node

Tags: javascript, hide, element, show

I have an HTML page with some paragraphs which I would like to show or hide via Javascript.  What should I do? Do I have to use the display property in the CSS file too?
Thank you

EDIT:  Since the paragraphs will be the error messages of a form, I'd like that at the beginning none of them were visibile.

Comment: it depends on when you want to hide them ...

Comment: provide some code what you tried so far

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this :

To hide :

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.display = 'none';
```

To show:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: First set their css as display:none; and then show it using js as above.

Comment: I would recommend (if possible) not to show elements by setting `node.style.display = 'block';`. I would rather just set `node.style.display = '';` so `display: none` gets removed and there is no need to override display property (as it could be different from "block"). Of course this wouldn't work if there is some `display: none` refering to that node in CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

To hide initially do this and better you put them in span not para

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $("span").hide();
 });
```

And whenever you need them to show call a javascript function on submit button and show using same

```
$("span").show();
```

But do not do like this this will show all messages, Put your if else logic and than show them by Id or class using jquery

```
$("#id").show();
$(".class").show();
```

Comment: OP has not requested anything to do with jQuery. This question does also not have a jQuery tag attached so a jQuery solution is not helpful in the context of providing a JavaScript only solution.